# Visual Studio 13, redirect a HTML5 webpage to external website?

Tags: javascript, windows, redirect, visual-studio-2012

I'm not experienced with Visual Studio 13 at all, but I managed to compile a simple HTML5 website so that it displays in an app.

I run a website, that I'd basically like to integrate into a Windows 8.1 UI app. I've tried code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://mywebsite.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='http://mywebsite.com'>link to example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

however it gives me an APPHOST9624 error. Even when I click on the HREF link it fails.

Obviously I'm going about this in the wrong way, so my question is. How do I create a Windows 8.1 store app that simply displays the external website fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You actually want to integrate the website in your store app so this solution won't work for you, just noticed that :) There also seems to be a [WebView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702) though all examples are in XAML, so it might not be supported in HTML5 apps...

I would recommend you launch the default browser with that new URI, though that would open a new browser instance, not sure if that's what you want in your case. For that, try calling

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701480)